# Read wp-config without loading the rest of WordPress - i.e. wp-settings, etc

Tags: wp-config

I'd like to read the database settings in `wp-config.php`. However, if I do a `require("wp-config.php");` it loads up the entire WordPress environment.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can read all the constants defined in wp-config.php from any place you want. If you have something like this in your wp-config.php

```
define('DB_NAME', 'some_value');
```

You can do this for example in your functions.php file

```
echo DB_NAME;
```

Constants are globally accessible from everywhere.

So please think about this approach.